# tkinter issue on Python3: happens on Mac OS X, not on Windows 10

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

as title says, same code, same Python 3 version on both computers, one runs Mac OSX, the other Win10.

I am at a total loss as to why this is happening and I'd really appreciate some explanation of what's going on here. I am not new to python coding, but I am inexperienced with tkinter and GUI design (mostly).

PS.: It runs fine on Windows 10 (i.e., outputs what I want), but it won't run on Mac OSX (i.e., hitting "run" button on GUI does nothing, apparently; entry text box is missing?).

Thank you!

Here's what I get on Win 10
[image: Here's what I get on Win 10]

Here's what I get on Mac OSX
[image: MacOSX]

And here is my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import math as m
from tkinter import *

root= tk.Tk()
root.title('Cloze Generator')


frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()

freq = Label(frame, text='Convert every how many words:')
freq.pack( side = LEFT )
#canvas.create_window(50, 100, window=freq)

fr = StringVar()
entry1 = Entry(frame, textvariable=fr)
entry1.pack( side = RIGHT)

canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width = 800, height = 700)
canvas.pack()

entry = tk.Text(root, height=15, width=90) 
canvas.create_window(400, 200, window=entry)

def cloze ():  
    x1 = entry.get('1.0','end')
    originalText = x1

    text = originalText.split()
    code = '{1:SHORTANSWER:='
    newText = ''
    i = 0
    fr = int(entry1.get())

    for word in text:
        i += 1
        if i % fr == 0:
            if word[-1] == '.':
                wordDot = word[:-1] 
                if len(wordDot) > 1: 
                    newWord = wordDot[:m.floor(len(word)/2)]
                    answer = wordDot[m.floor(len(word)/2):]
                    outWord = newWord + code + answer + '}'
                    newText += outWord + '. '
                else:
                    newText += word + '. '
            elif word[-1] == ',':
                wordDot = word[:-1] 
                if len(wordDot) > 1: 
                    newWord = wordDot[:m.floor(len(word)/2)]
                    answer = wordDot[m.floor(len(word)/2):]
                    outWord = newWord + code + answer + '}'
                    newText += outWord + ', '
                else:
                    newText += word + ', '        
            else:
                if len(word) > 1: 
                    newWord = word[:m.floor(len(word)/2)]
                    answer = word[m.floor(len(word)/2):]
                    outWord = newWord + code + answer + '}'
                    newText += outWord + ' '
                else:
                    newText += word + ' '
        else:
            newText += word + ' '

    outText = tk.Text(root, height=15, width=90)
    outText.insert(tk.END, newText)
    canvas.create_window(400, 500, window=outText)

button = tk.Button(text='Run', command=cloze)
canvas.create_window(50, 350, window=button)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: ***`.create_window`***: Why do you create a new window instead to use the existing one?

Comment: If the problem is with the appearance of the text widget we don't need all of the code in the `cloze` function _for the purposes of this question_, do we?

Comment: I add the whole code, since it's fairly short, so people can run it and understand why I did certain things, like create a new window, and also because I do not know where tkinter is producing the odd behavior. There's a canvas, and on the canvas there are four windows. One window is input (number), seconds is input (text), the other is a button, and the other is output (only shown when there's output).

Comment: _" I do not know where tkinter is producing the odd behavior."_ - that's why we request that you create a [mcve]. Doing so helps you learn which code is producing the odd behavior. That's how you solve programming problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

The text widget isn't missing. It's there, but it has no border and its background is the same background as its parent so it blends in with the background.

Different platforms have different default values for widgets. On OSX, the default relief for a text widget is "flat" and the borderwidth is 0, whereas on windows it is "sunken" and 1.

To see the widget you can explicitly set the borderwidth and relief if you want it to look the same on both platforms:

```
entry = tk.Text(root, height=15, width=90, bd=1, relief="sunken")
```

> PS.: It runs fine on Windows 10 (i.e., outputs what I want), but it won't run on Mac OSX (i.e., hitting "run" button on GUI does nothing, apparently; entry text box is missing?).

I can't duplicate that behavior. When I click the run button after inserting text and typing a number in the entry widget, the function appears to work.

Comment: Wouldn't using `ttk` widgets with one of the standard themes give the same look on different platforms? (I don't have a mac or windows machine available to test, or I would have tried.)

Comment: The weirdest thing about it is that on a first (few) runs, it did show the boarders on Mac OS X. Next day, not anymore.

Comment: @Gustav: that's simply not possible, unless you upgraded something.